# AnyLogic 8.8.5 Error when recalculating the train route (NullPointerException)

Tags: anylogic

I found that the TrainMoveTo block always throws an error (NullPointerException) when recalculating the route (when, for example, the path is blocked) if the train's speed is not currently equal to its cruising speed. The code that is listed in the comments completely eliminates the error in this simple model:

[image]

[image]

If it is written about this somewhere in the help, or the problem is in something else, please let us know in the answer or comments, but in my case, only the code in the comments is enough for the train to change from the upper track to the lower one when the first one is blocked.